# dynamic drop down button using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

how do to create a dynamic drop down box using java script, and populate list in it?
here's my fiddle, please help!

button

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#b_id").click(function(){
    $("#div_id").append($('<select/>'));

})

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L4reds/wmqcd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some more code in adding inner html [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/wmqcd/2/) and it will work

```
$("#div_id").append($('<select><option value="1">one</option></select>'))
```

Comment: Yes, single line append is good. But Is it comfortable to maintain a long list of option near about ten or more options.

Comment: yes in case if you wanna shorten the code then storing the values in an array and then looping in javascript to create the HTML string for select option can be also done

Answer (score 1):

Just add this script to your code I hope this work for you effectively :

Refer this Fiddle : [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wmqcd/13/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#b_id").click(function(){
        var drop_list = '<select>';
        drop_list += '<option value="Asia">Asia</option>';
        drop_list += '<option value="UK">UK</option>';
        drop_list += '<option value="USA">USA</option>';        
        drop_list += '</select>';    
        $("#div_id").append(drop_list);    
    })    
});
```

Comment: That's good. If my suggestion is helpful then please accept it or if anybody else then accept that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just add options after you append the select :

```
$("#b_id").click(function(){
    $("#div_id").append($('<select/>'));
    $("#div_id select").append($('<option value="1">one</option>'));
    $("#div_id select").append($('<option value="2">two</option>'));
});
```

Comment: thanks, seem to work just fine... but can i set attribute to the drop down.. and how?

Comment: That you can do while creating the select itself. `$("#div_id").append($('<select id="mydd" class="myclass" />'));`

Answer (score 0):

You can add options what did similar to `select` using jQuery.

[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) - set/get value to element
[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) - set.get innerHTML of an element

```
$('<option>').val('1').text('option1').appendTo($('select'));
```

Your code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#b_id").click(function(){
        $("#div_id").append($('<select/>'));
       $('<option>').val('1').text('option1').appendTo($('select'));       
    })

});
```

Check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wmqcd/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#b_id").click(function(){

```
var cmbType = $("<select></select>").attr("id",'cmbType').attr("name", 'cmbType').attr("class", "rtctrl");
var Types = {
    0: '--Select--',
    1: 'DEED',
    2: 'FORECLOSURE',
    3: 'TAX SALE',
    4: 'ASSESSOR',
    5: 'RENTAL'
};
$.each(Types, function (val, text) {
    cmbType.append(
    $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
);
});

 $("#div_id").append(cmbType);
});
```

});

check: http://jsfiddle.net/wmqcd/10/